# Text alignment issue in ipython notebook

Tags: text, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with my notebooks. I can't manage to change text alignment to left. Any suggestions?

Aligned to right:

[image: Aligned to right]

Can even see the code's beggining:

[image: can even see the code's beggining]